# Como enviar essa variável "dt" para o promise.done?

Tags: javascript, promises

Eu tenho a seguinte linha de javascript:

```
...
var refundVal = $( ".refundVal" ).val();
var dt={ 
         orderId:orderId,
         refundVal:refundVal,
         process:btnProcess
        };

window.srObjc.confirm("message $"+refundVal+" ?").promise.done(function(dt) 
{
         console.log("test0");  //L1
         console.log(dt);       //L1
         console.log("test1");  //L1
         console.log(refundVal);//L4

         //Ajax
         var request =$.ajax({
                               url: "pagamentos.php",
                               type: "POST",
                               data: dt,
                               dataType: "json"
                              });

         request.done(function(dataset){  

                                  var resut = dataset;
                                  var str = JSON.stringify(resut, null, 2);
                                  alert(str);//test


                                  container.html(render(resut));
                                  $('#raw-data').html(syntaxHighlight(str));
                                  console.log(str);//test
                         }); 

}//window.srObjc.confirm
```

Neste exemplo o valor refundVal é igual a $1.

esse é o resultado em console.log:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O valor de "dt" está aparecendo "ok". Eu esperava ver um objeto com os valores no log doconsole.
E o valor de refund val está correto =$1, e eu não estava esperando isso pois não estou enviando esse valor no parâmetro da função `promise.done(function(dt)`.

Então, a pergunta é como faço para enviar esse objeto para dentro da função e ver o display correto no console.log ?

Comment: `dt` é global nesse código que mostraste. Então se não declarares (via parametro da função) uma `dt` nova, ela vai estar acessível. Tira `dt` daqui: `promise.done(function(dt)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que acontece é que ao adicionar `dt` na função de callback do promise, aqui nesta linha:

```
window.srObjc.confirm("message $"+refundVal+" ?").promise.done(function(dt)
```

você acaba criando uma nova variável no escopo da função, porém com o mesmo nome da variável `dt` que está no escopo global, nesta parte do código:

```
var dt={ 
     orderId:orderId,
     refundVal:refundVal,
     process:btnProcess
    };
```

Se você remover a variável da função de callback, ou alterando seu nome, você terá o resultado desejado.

Para entender melhor de escopo sugiro [este artigo](http://loopinfinito.com.br/2014/10/29/hoisting-e-escopo-em-javascript/) que explica bem como funciona o escopo de variáveis.